# How to display array values in Pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I am new to TradingView Pine scripting. I have been given a working Pine script that creates annotations on a chart after specific conditions have been met.

How do I display values from an array?  I want to correlate intermediate values with another data provider.  Can I use tables, labels or debug prints?

I want to print the RL10 values after the linear regression call:

```
//@version=4

strat = false
RL10 = linreg(close, 10, 0)
```

How do I proceed?  I am too new to Pine for Google searches to help...

Answer (score 0):

Since the array values will be dynamic, you can either use `label` or `table` to display the values.

Just get the value with `array.get()` and display it.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

my_arr = array.from(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

first_elem = array.get(my_arr, 0)
first_elem_str = "First element: " + str.tostring(first_elem)

var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1, color.yellow)

if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, high, first_elem_str)
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, first_elem_str)
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't answer my question. This code statically displays the first element of the array over the last candle bar. I need a solution that would ideally display the last n dates/array values, or at a minimum, show a specific array value as I mouse over or click on a prior day. Can I display multiple dates/array values at once?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this myself. As a Pine beginner, I didn't realize series and arrays are different.  So my initial question was poorly worded.

The best way to capture intermediate results is by exporting a CSV from TradingView. The export feature is only available to Platinum subscribers, so this wouldn't work for me.

I created a label that printed the last 60 values of the price and linreg series, along with the date.  I used screen capture software to grab the text and OCR it into a CSV file.

Here is my code

```
//@version=5
indicator("My log script", "log1", true)

var dates = array.new_string()

stringGen(_index, _price, _linreg) => 
    // get most recent date
    _todaysDate = array.pop(dates)

    line = str.tostring(_index) + "," + _todaysDate + "," + str.tostring(_price, "#.00") + ", " + str.tostring(_linreg, "#.0000") + "\n"

RL10 = ta.linreg(close, 10, 0)

todaysDate = str.format("{0,time,yyyy-MM-dd}", time_close)
array.push(dates, todaysDate)

string debugScring = "// index,date,close,linreg\n"

if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to 60-1
        debugScring := debugScring + stringGen(i, close[i], RL10[i])

    label.new(bar_index, high, debugScring,style=label.style_label_center,  color=color.new(color.white, 0), textcolor= color.new(color.black, 0), textalign=text.align_left)
```

[image: TrdingView Screenshot]